# iTMSTransporter could not be updated

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes-store, itmstransporter

I am trying to upload an app to iTunes Store and I am stuck to Autheticating with iTunes. I have tried many solutions I found such as disabling firewall and  changing HTTPS port from 443 to 80 in file Applications > Xcode > Contents > Applications > Application Loader > Contents > MacOS > itms > java > lib - net.properties.

Now I am trying to update iTMSTransporter by calling

```
 mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/ 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
```

but everytime is stoping to a different point and the update never completes.